# What's the point of Clock.withZone?

Tags: java

`java.time.Clock` provides access to `millis` and `instant`, but no access to anything that relies upon timezones. Yet it contains a timezone and requires one for construction. It seems to only be used for equals/hashcode.

```
static final class SystemClock extends Clock implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 6740630888130243051L;
    private final ZoneId zone;

    SystemClock(ZoneId zone) {
        this.zone = zone;
    }
    @Override
    public ZoneId getZone() {
        return zone;
    }
    @Override
    public Clock withZone(ZoneId zone) {
        if (zone.equals(this.zone)) {  // intentional NPE
            return this;
        }
        return new SystemClock(zone);
    }
    @Override
    public long millis() {
        return System.currentTimeMillis();
    }
    @Override
    public Instant instant() {
        return Instant.ofEpochMilli(millis());
    }
    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        if (obj instanceof SystemClock) {
            return zone.equals(((SystemClock) obj).zone);
        }
        return false;
    }
    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return zone.hashCode() + 1;
    }
    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "SystemClock[" + zone + "]";
    }
}
```

Is there a reason for including `ZoneId` in this class?

Answer (score 4):

The [docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/Clock.html) describe the whole purpose of Clock as being basically a (millis-generator, time zone) pair, especially for testing:

> Instances of this class are used to find the current instant, which can be interpreted using the stored time-zone to find the current date and time. As such, a clock can be used instead of System.currentTimeMillis() and TimeZone.getDefault().
>
> Use of a Clock is optional. All key date-time classes also have a now() factory method that uses the system clock in the default time zone. **The primary purpose of this abstraction is to allow alternate clocks to be plugged in as and when required.** Applications use an object to obtain the current time rather than a static method. **This can simplify testing.**

(emphasis added)

For instance,  if you want to test how your class acts at a specific instant in a specific time zone, you can inject a `Clock.fixed` instance. In production code, you'd use one of the `Clock.system*` factories.

Comment: See, e.g., `LocalDate.now(Clock)`[1], which queries not only the instant but also the zone.

[1] https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDate.html#now-java.time.Clock-

Comment: Thanks @RobStarling. This makes sense.